# Can't create sidebars in Python Sphinx html output?

Tags: python, python-sphinx, sidebar, navigationbar, toctree

I'm documenting my Python project using Sphinx tool and my HTML output currently looks like this:

[image]

As you can see the tool bar has "Navigation" heading with nothing under it. When I add the following code to my `conf.py` file, the HTML toolbar remains the same (with nothing under Navigation):

```
html_sidebars = {
'**': [
    'about.html',
    'navigation.html',
    'searchbox.html'
]}
```

Do I have to create some file on my own or am I doing something wrong?

My goal is for the HTML to look like this:

[image]

I assume it's the same issue as adding a logo to the HTML which I also couldn't create.

These are the contents of the `index.rst` file in my Sphinx project:

```
.. Sample documentation master file, created by
   sphinx-quickstart on Thu Jul  5 09:19:15 2018.
   You can adapt this file completely to your liking, but it should at least
   contain the root `toctree` directive.

Welcome to Sample's documentation!
====================================

.. toctree::
   :maxdepth: 2
   :caption: Contents:



Indices and tables
==================

* :ref:`genindex`
* :ref:`modindex`
* :ref:`search`
```

Comment: Edit your question to show the content of your `index.rst`. You are likely missing a `toctree` entry or filenames under it.

Comment: And yeah, that file's table of contents (currently empty) is what goes into your side menu

Comment: Added the code. I read some docs on the toctree but still can't figure out how to insert a Navigation bar so it actually references to other places in the docs. It sounds to me like a task that includes heavy html building ? Because it is custom ? Or maybe I'm missing something and Sphinx generates that stuff for me ?

Comment: The toctree is empty. You need to add entries to it (the names of the other RST documents). See http://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/stable/markup/toctree.html